# fglrxinfo shows wrong data for graphics card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card

I'm trying to set up a linux partition running Ubuntu-Mate 14.04.2.  I have an AMD Radeon R9 290 installed.  I was able to successfully download and instal the catalyst drivers, but when I run `fglrxinfo`, I get the following:

```
$ fglrxinfo 
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 10.1.3)
```

heres my `lspci`:

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep -i vga
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0412] (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem- BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290] [1002:67b1] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    BridgeCtl: Parity- SERR- NoISA- VGA- MAbort- >Reset- FastB2B-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: By any chance are you referring to this line `display: :0.0  screen: 0` shown by `fglrxinfo` as wrong data? Or may be something else?

Comment: @Ayan I'm using [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) and I guess it should say `display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500 Series       
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11399 Compatibility Profile Context` the performance of the card is very poor.  I boot a game and I get like 1 FPS

Comment: Okay. Got it. I use a R9 280X and I generally install the driver from Ubuntu's Additional Drivers app. In the app select "Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)" and click Apply Changes. Wait for the app to download and install the drivers then reboot the PC. I actually never used the `lspci` to check the installation, once installed I open the Catalyst Control Center and there it shows the correct info. But just now I ran both `fglrx` and `lspci` and the info displayed by both are correct to my knowledge.

Comment: I don't play games in Ubuntu so I cannot tell you much about the cards gaming performance but normal desktop animations, video playback, picture editing, web page rendering are smooth on a FHD display using the proprietary drivers. And the above mentioned way is a lot more easy and hassle free way to install the drivers and its related components. Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Apparently I'm just destined to never run Linux in this machine. I tried to boot into Ubuntu, and it got stuck at the splash screen. Nothing was responding. So I tried to boot to a love CD and the disk never loaded. The drive didn't spin up. Basically there's no way for me to get to a Linux partition. Thanks for trying man.